# Do we need internet access to all the servers while bootstraping with conjure-up?

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack

I am trying to follow the steps that are provided to setup openstack with ubuntu maas juju autopilot.

I am stuck at one step where I am running

```
conjure-up --bootstrap-to <hostname>.
```

This command got stuck at

> Fetching Juju Agent 2.1.2

Waiting for sometime and then logged into the server that was selected to bootstrap, found that its not able access internet. This server has two nics and one of them connected to external network (which has internet access to corporate firewall). Now, I edited the /etc/resolv.conf to put external network dns servers and dns search ahead of maas server dns and IP.
After this, the procedure could progress further, got into deploying haproxy, landscape-server, postgresql and rabbitmq-server. Here it was waiting for machine, and started deploying the second server.

Since, wakeonlan is not an option with 16.04, I have set manual for all the servers in the maas list. Using etherwake, I could turn on the server and deployment started on the second server.

Now, the question is does this second server also needs access to internet? Also, I have a question regarding, whether all the servers need internet access for some reason?
Is there a way to keep all the servers except MAAS controller node with in a  private network without internet access and serve all the internet access needs to through MAAS controller?

In my setup I have a MAAS controller which has two nics one connected to internet and other to a private switch.
I have also connected two more servers in the similar manner, so that juju and landscape get up and running.

Please let me know in case you need any specific info to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, its difficult to get answers in this forum related to maas/juju/autopilot.

The answer to my question is: Yes.
Its done by MAAS server who could act like a router:
Sample firewall modifications on MAAS server is here for the same:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o eno1 -i eno2 -s 10.0.0.1/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno2 -j MASQUERADE
```

here 10.xxx is the internal network.